# What is the best way to limit text input entry to numbers, lowercase letters, and certain symbols?

Tags: javascript

Without using jQuery, what is the best way to limit text entry of a textbox to numbers, lowercase letters and a given set of symbols (for example `-` and `_`)? If the user enters an uppercase letter, I would like it to be automatically converted to a lowercase letter, and if the user enters a symbol not within the given set, I would like to be able to instantly show a validation error (show some element adjacent to or below the text box).

What's the cleanest cross-browser way of doing this without the aid of jQuery?

Comment: why not use jQuery? do you also want to forgo other JS Frameworks I.e. mootolls etc.?

Comment: I do indeed want to forgo other JavaScript frameworks; I'm simply looking for a "pure" solution right now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Attach the following to your elements onkeyup event.

```
function onkeyup() 
{
    var el = document.getElementById("id"); // or however you want to get it

    el.value = el.value.toLowerCase(); // covert to lower case

    if (el.value.match(/[^-\d\w]/)) // check for illegal characters
    {
        // show validation error
        ...
        // remove invalid characters
        el.value = el.value.replace(/[^-\d\w]/g, "");
    }
    else
    {
        // hide validation error
    }
}
```

The regex matches any character which is not a digit, a letter, a hyphen or an underscore.

Comment: If you are going to do this with multiple inputs, it would be a good idea to create a plugin http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Authoring

Comment: There's already a plugin for that. It's called Jquery Validation. But the OP doesn't want to use a framework.

Comment: This solution doesn't prevent users from entering illegal characters, it only alerts them when the input is invalid. Is there a way to drop the illegal character so that it simply can't be typed in the text box? Also, will this work with such things as pasting into the field?

Comment: @Adam, I read your question as wanting to show a validation error. To prevent the character getting entered, you would either have to use the keydown event and `return false` or do a regex replace at the same place it shows the validation error. See my edit.